# Finding all symlinks in a directory and echoing their paths and owners of the original file

Tags: bash, algorithm

I'm trying to make a script that will find all symlinks in a directory that the script is currently in, and it will echo *"This 'link' refers to 'path' and it's owner is 'owner'.*

I've come up with this solution so far, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for each in .
do
  echo "Link '$1' refers to" $(realpath $1) "and its owner is: " $(ls -ld $(realpath $1) | awk '{print $3}')
end for
```

And this it the error that it gives me:

```
jakub.kacerek@perun:~$ ./najdi_symlink.sh
./najdi_symlink.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
jakub.kacerek@perun:~$
```

I'm 100% sure that the error is in the for loop, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: A bash `for` loop is closed with `done` (matching the `do`) not `end for`.

Answer (score 2):

Well after a quick thought I found out the solution for it, it may not be the smartest one but it gets the job done.

The solution is:

```
#!/bin/bash

for each in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -ls | awk '{print $11}'); do
  echo "Link '$each' refers to" $(realpath $each) "and its owner is: " $(ls -ld $(realpath $each) | awk '{print $3}')
done
```

Comment: Neat answer man!

Answer (score 0):

I liked  the assignment. I've figured it out.

> I'm trying to make a script that will find all symlinks in a directory that the script is currently in, and it will echo "This 'link' refers to 'path' and it's owner is 'owner'.

You might need to change the strings, but the actual code works.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for item in * ; do
  if [ ! -L $item ]
  then
    echo "filename: '$item' is NOT a symlink"
  else
    printf "filename: '$item' is a symlink " && echo $item | awk '{printf("%s ->", $1); system("readlink -f " $1)}' && printf 'owner is: ' ; stat -c '%U' $item
  fi
done
```

Example output:

```sh
[vagrant@vm-local-1 ~]$ ./a.sh
filename: 'a.sh' is NOT a symlink
filename: 'hi.jar' is NOT a symlink
filename: 'ho' is a symlink ho ->/tmp/abc/ho
owner is: vagrant
filename: 'one' is NOT a symlink
filename: 'test.jar' is NOT a symlink
filename: 'test.tar.gz' is NOT a symlink
filename: 'two' is a symlink two ->/home/vagrant/one
owner is: vagrant
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you figured out you can use `find`, why do you keep using a `for`-loop?

```
find . -type l -exec echo {} : $(realpath {}) \;
```

This is not complete but it shows what you can do:

- basic usage of `find`
- `find`, combined with `{}` (`find` result)
- You can launch commands (like `realpath`) on the `find` result.

Have fun :-)